# create hotel book with dev express scheduler and VB.net 2010

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

i need help.
i want to build a hotel management system.
i will build this app with vb.net 2010 and dev expres 13.1.5.
i have create a hotel book with xtra scheduler like picture bellow,
[image: hotel book with xtra scheduler]
but i have a problem, i don't understand how to add other resource into the scheduler.
i want my scheduler like this picture :
[image: hotel book]
i have searched on google, but i didn't find.
please tell me how to make it, or tell me the keyword that i should type on google

Answer (score 0):

With DevExpress Scheduler you can implement this layout either combining Image and Text options for a scheduler's [resource headers](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1775) or with using the [ResourcesTree](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument10685) control.

Take a look at the [Resources for Appointments](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1756) help article for more details.

Comment: still confuse... i just need to add one column to put the status of the room (dirty,clean,out of order)..